# Parametrization of a knot isotopy

Tags: general-topology, parametrization, knot-theory

I am working on a computer visualization of a knot isotopy of the standard unknot embedding to an unknot with a Reidemeister I move. Does anyone have a formula?

Comment: A formula for what ?

Comment: Do you mean a description through equations continuously dependent of a certain "time" parameter of a tubular surface that unknots itself ?

Comment: No answer to my question ? Besides, an article that maybe will provide you some inspiration : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.2819.pdf

Comment: You may also find [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6b5c/9135c345354d2fa56be20d0a00dd5abfda7a.pdf?_ga=2.219570462.642077859.1613256437-1603192576.1612117105) interesting.

Comment: I want a formula $r:[0,2\pi] \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^3$ where for each $s \in [0,1]$, $r_s = r(-,s)$ is a parametrization for a knot, and where $r_0$ is the standard embedding of the unknot and $r_1$ is a twisted unknot introduced by performing a Reidemeister Type I move.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very likely not what you're looking for, but I think it illuminates what a Reidemeister I move "is".

Consider this parameterization of an unknotted circle:

[image: An unknot parameterization]

Depending on which direction you're looking at it, the projected diagram has either zero or one crossings:

[image: front view][image: top view]

So, by animating the projections of this loop as we rotate it, we get this animation illustrating a sequence of Reidemeister I moves:

[image: Reidemeister I]

The homotopy of these plane curves is
$$f_t(\theta) = (\cos t \sin 2\theta + \sin t \cos \theta, \sin\theta).$$
(Note: in the above animation the slider is mislabeled and it should read $t$ rather than $\theta$.)

The Reidemeister moves come from examining the kinds of singularities in diagrams that occur generically during an isotopy of the projected knots, and Reidemeister I moves come, basically, from when a portion of a curve like this rotates.

The following is potentially more useful.  If you analyze a Reidemeister I singularity carefully, you can isotope the isotopy to give a nice local model for it.  This is a polynomially defined local model for the Reidemeister I singularity:
$$f_t(s)=(s^2,s,s^3-ts)$$
where $s\in\mathbb{R}$ and $t\in[-1,1]$.

Projecting this onto the XZ axis gives this:

[image: polynomial local model, XZ plane]

Projecting it onto the YZ plane, we can see that what's happening is that a bit of the knot is being turned over:

[image: polynomial local model, YZ plane]

Comment: Very good explanations. Only a little remark: I wouldn't call the first closed curve a "circle"...